# Best markup format for future-proofing large text chunks?

Tags: storage, markdown, markup, multimarkdown

I have a number of records (=< 100) that contain sizeable chunks of text that require marking up (semantically: lists, headings, tables, links, quotations, etc...) before storing in a re-usable file format.

When stored, it is likely to remain more or less unchanged for as many years into the future as possible.

It contains some non-ascii, so UTF-8 is required. I started using HTML, then considered Markdown... but would like to know what people think is **the most future-proof markup format for long-term storage**? The content is initially for a (mostly static) website, but may be used as content for other outputs.

Finally, opinions on the **choice of storage** for long-term use - database, separate documents...? Changes to records will be infrequent and edited by only 1-3 people, and read access should increase over time.

---

### Update:

I've finally chosen the common features (e.g. for tables) between [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/), [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) and [Kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html) as the text format (Markdown omits too many HTML tags), and am converting the resulting files to html with Kramdown. Now I'm trying out [iOS Markdown editors](http://markedapp.com/) that can handle an extended Markdown and sync via Dropbox to my desk/laptop.

Comment: 8 views, no answers/opinions? C'mon! Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Any storage not designed for long-term archiving will break**.

It is not so much a question of database vs. filesystem, but how to ensure that no (silent) data corruption happens, and how to migrate data. I can give you no definitive answers, because it depends on a lot of factors (incl. costs), but here are a few resources:

- [Building Better Long-Term Archival Storage System](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/news/events/other_meetings/storage11/docs/26_miller.pdf), Talk by Miller/Storer at the Library of Congress
- [The Digital Dilemma](http://www.oscars.org/science-technology/council/projects/digitaldilemma/), Book aimed at movie archiving, but highlights some of the issues in long term archiving.
- [Project Honeycomb](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+honeycomb/), a project by SUN for open source long-term archiving, but discontinued.

I have no real answer for the format question, but I think HTML + UTF-8 should be readable even in decades, but document it.

Comment: That's *exactly* the kind of answer I'd been waiting for - thanks.